# How can I make parameters set by an array of buttons known to other quantities in my model?

Tags: manipulate, dynamic, scoping

With help from @m_goldberg, I developed the following model:

```
Clear[n, vLabels, muAVE, muKSA, AA, BB, btnLbl];
SeedRandom[124];
n = 5;
vLabels = {1 -> AGR, 2 -> FIS, 3 -> CO1, 4 -> CO2, 5 -> MA1};
AA = RandomInteger[5, {n, n}];
BB = RandomInteger[5, {n, n}];
{RB[1] = 0.9, RB[2] = 0.5,   RB[3] = 0.35, RB[4] = 0.48, RB[5] = 0.15};
{eRB[1] = 0.55, eRB[2] = 0.44, eRB[3] = 0.70, eRB[4] = 0.25, 
eRB[5] = 0.65};
muAVE = {0.48, 0.55, 0.53, 0.5, 0.33};
muKSA = {0.87, 0.87, 0.97, 0.89, 0.45};
btnLbl = SetterBar[#, {0, 1}] &;

Manipulate[
  scenarioMU = muKSA - ((muKSA - muAVE)/b);
  DynamicModule[{gr, mu, gg, rr, AAg, BBr, tags, γ, μ},
    gr[i_] := eRB[i]*RB[i]* γ[i];
    mu[i_] := scenarioMU[[i]]*μ[i];
    gg = DiagonalMatrix[Table[1 + gr[i], {i, n}]];
    rr = DiagonalMatrix[Table[1 + mu[i], {i, n}]];
    AAg = gg.AA;
    BBr = rr.BB;
    tags = Range[n];
    Set[γ[#], 0] & /@ tags;
    Set[μ[#], 0] & /@ tags;
    Column[
      {Dynamic[
         TableForm[
           {Button[btnLbl[γ[#]], γ[#] = Mod[γ[#] + 1, 2], 
              Appearance -> None] & /@ tags, 
            Button[btnLbl[μ[#]], μ[#] = Mod[μ[#] + 1, 2], 
              Appearance -> None] & /@ tags}, 
            TableHeadings -> {{"γ", "μ"}, tags /. vLabels}]], 
       Spacer[36],
       Dynamic[
         TableForm[{gr /@ tags, mu /@ tags}, 
           TableHeadings -> 
             {{"Output growth rate (γ)", "Markup (μ)"}, tags /. vLabels}]], 
       Spacer[36],
       {Dynamic[AAg // MatrixForm], Dynamic[BBr // MatrixForm]}}]],
  {{b, 10, "Markup \nscenario (b)"}, 0.1, 10, 0.1}]
```

This code is missing the link between parameters in button bar and matrix multiplication below:

```
AAg = gg.AA;
BBr = rr.BB;
```

I want to link the parameters in the button bar (gamma and mu) to the above matrix multiplication and run the code for different values of parameter `b`, which is set by a manipulator control in the `Manipulate` expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I fixed things up. You might not like the look of the outpur produced by the revised code, but it has the virtue of working. Working is better than pretty. If you can'r make it pretty on your own, you can always ask another question about fixing up the GUI.

```
SeedRandom[124];
n = 5;
tags = Range[n];
vLabels = {1 -> AGR, 2 -> FIS, 3 -> CO1, 4 -> CO2, 5 -> MA1};
AA = RandomInteger[5, {n, n}];
BB = RandomInteger[5, {n, n}];
{RB[1] = 0.9, RB[2] = 0.5, RB[3] = 0.35, RB[4] = 0.48, RB[5] = 0.15};
{eRB[1] = 0.55, eRB[2] = 0.44, eRB[3] = 0.70, eRB[4] = 0.25, eRB[5] = 0.65};
muAVE = {0.48, 0.55, 0.53, 0.5, 0.33};
muKSA = {0.87, 0.87, 0.97, 0.89, 0.45};
btnLbl = SetterBar[#, {0, 1}] &;

DynamicModule[{gr, mu, gg, rr, AAg, BBr, γ, μ, scenarioMU},
  scenarioMU = ConstantArray[1, n]; 
  gr[i_] := eRB[i] RB[i] γ[i];
  mu[i_] := scenarioMU[[i]] μ[i];
  Set[γ[#], 0] & /@ tags;
  Set[μ[#], 0] & /@ tags;
  Manipulate[
    scenarioMU = muKSA - (muKSA - muAVE)/b;
    gg = DiagonalMatrix[Table[1 + gr[i], {i, n}]];
    rr = DiagonalMatrix[Table[1 + mu[i], {i, n}]];
    Column[
      {Dynamic[
         TableForm[
           {Button[btnLbl[γ[#]], γ[#] = Mod[γ[#] + 1, 2],
              Appearance -> None] & /@ tags,
            Button[btnLbl[μ[#]], μ[#] = Mod[μ[#] + 1, 2],
              Appearance -> None] & /@ tags},
            TableHeadings -> {{"γ", "μ"}, tags /. vLabels}]],
       Spacer[36],
       Dynamic[
         TableForm[{gr /@ tags, mu /@ tags}, 
           TableHeadings -> 
             {{"Output growth rate (γ)", "Markup (μ)"}, tags /. vLabels}]],
       Spacer[36],
       Dynamic[gg.AA // MatrixForm],
       Spacer[36],
       Dynamic[rr.BB // MatrixForm]}],
    {{b, 10, "Markup\nscenario (b)"}, 0.1, 10, 0.1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
    TrackedSymbols :> {b, γ, μ}]]
```

[image: demo]

The problems you having were caused by number of things.

- incorrect evaluation order. That lead to interdependent functions and variables getting defined in different scopes which caused updating failures.
- initialization being done too late or not at all
- updating of `γ` and `μ`was not happening because they are defined outside the `Manipulate` expression, so the `Manipulate`code didn't know they needed to be tracked. This was corrected by using the option `TrackedSymbols`.

Comment: @TugrulTemel. I have corrected a minor error in the code. `tags` shouldn't be evaluated in the dynamic module. It is static and can be once along with the other static parameters.

Comment: @TugrulTemel. No,  the dot products have to done where I put them. or they will never be updated when the controls are used. This is one the evaluations you were doing in the wrong place in the code you posted in the question.

Comment: @TugrulTemel. Sorry but I can not work with the information you supply in your latest comment. It is incomplete. You need to post another question showing the full code you are working with now.

Comment: The above code you developed answers my original question. I just wanted to know if there is a way to adjust the above code in such a way to change the color of the button from blue to green, for example, when I make a choice. Currently, the blue buttons are shown and I want to change the blue color to green when I choose the associated parameter. This will allow me to easily see what I chose as a parameter.

Comment: @TugrulTemel. I don't know how to change the color used to highlight the selected state of a control other than to choose one of two colors that MacOS allows. Green is not one of those two choices. I think I how to fake such behavior with a button. I will develop my idea and post it as an answer if you pose this problem in a new question. It is to your advantage to do so; you might get another answer, better than mine.